# curl_easy_cleanup doesnt clear curl pointer

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

When I perform an **curl_easy_perform** I then do a **curl_easy_cleanup** like so:

```
CURL* pEasy = nullptr;  
pEasy = curl_easy_init();
if (pEasy != nullptr)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasy, CURLOPT_USERNAME, user.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasy, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, pass.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasy, CURLOPT_URL, urlToConnectTo.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(pEasy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, OnReceiveHttpResponse);

    curl_easy_perform(pEasy);

    curl_easy_cleanup(pEasy);
}
```

I notice in my debugger the address of the pEasy pointer and its say 0x2af0ad18 but after I do the **curl_easy_cleanup** its still 0x2af0ad18.

Do I have to set it to nullptr after?
I would expect the curl_easy_cleanup to reset this for me???

Comment: _"Do I have to set it to nullptr after?"_ Probably. That the allocated memory was freed from the address in `pEasy` doesn't set it to `nullptr` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html

The function takes a pointer, how would you expect it to change the value of something in your local scope?

When you call `free(x)`, it doesn't set set `x` to `null` it just frees the memory, and that is the same thing `curl_easy_cleanup` is doing. Whether you want to set `pEasy` to nullptr or not afterwards is up to you, possibly good practice but unnecessary depending on the layout of your code and whether `pEasy` is about to go out of scope anyway.